# Ejecutar programa en c++ desde lua de forma independiente

Tags: lua

La Situación es la siguiente , yo estoy realizando desde lua la llamada a un programa :

```
os.execute("./mainc")
```

Este mainc tiene como particularidad, que no tiene que morir puesto que esta escuchando del puerto serie y va escribiendo sus cosas. El punto esta en que cuando llamo a esto desde lua la ejecución se queda esperando a que termine ./mainc.

He probado a crear hilos con

```
co = coroutine.create(function ()
    os.execute("./mainc")
  end)
coroutine.resume(co)
```

Pero esto realiza la misma acción, espera a ./mainc para continuar.

Alguno conoce alguna forma de realizar llamadas desde lua de forma que este simplemente realice la llamada sin esperar la finalización de la misma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua tiene `io.popen` para ejecutar programas sin bloquear:

```
io.popen("./mainc")
```

Lo que intentaste no funciona porque no se creó un hilo, sino una corutina.
Solo se puede mantener una corutina activa a la vez y si esa bloquea las demas
tienen que esperar a que termine.

Comment: ahí te pasa lo mismo que en la primera ejecución , hasta que no termina la ejecución de mainc no pasa de ahí. Lo que yo busco es que mainc se ejecute, no necesito leer de él, incluso que si lua termine este siga (eso se puede hacer quitando el padre en ejecución pero no me deja hacer nada después de eso ).

Comment: Que raro, en la documentación dice que lo abre en otro proceso (y lo probé con "sleep 10" que bloquea y puedo imprimir cosas mientras se ejecuta). Lo de que se siga ejecutando despues de que termine Lua te lo debo. También podrías dejar que el shell se ocupe de dejarlo abierto en segundo plano con `os.execute("./mainc &")` (nota el "&" al final).